# Changing view in TabSpec

Tags: android, android-tabs

In my app I'm using the following code to build my TabActivity -

```
contactsTabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.contacts))
            .setIndicator(chatHeaderView).setContent(R.id.contactList);
```

the contactList is a ListView that must be build in my TabActivity implementation (can not be build in regular Activity).

Some of the actions in my app required to change the contactList with groupList in the same tab.
How it can be done with out using intents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an adapter for the contact list, which your displaying on the ListView. When you need to update the list based on your action, just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method.